# Deleting substring in a string with delimiters in C

Tags: c

I need a help with a program (without using strtok() function) that should be doing this:

If the input is

```
car;dog;pet;elephant
```

and if the argument is 2, the ouput should be:

```
car;pet;elephant
```

if the argument is 4, the output should be:

```
car;dog;pet
```

and so on.

I've tried a lot of different solutions but nothing seems to work. So if anybody could help me, I would be really glad.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can help you learn how to fix it.

Comment: ***Show Your Code***  (We do not write your code for you)

Comment: `If the input is` How is the input stored? In what way? Please show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function removing the substring from the "csv style" line. It takes info the account empty strings and (probably most as I did not properly test it) border cases.

It is not using "heavy" string functions like `strtok` or `strdup` as I believe this exercise is to write it using arrays or pointers.

```
char *dupAndDelete(const char *str, char delim, int pos)
{
    char *out = NULL;
    int cpos = 1;

    if(str)
    {
        out = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        char *wrk = out;
        if(out)
        {
            while(*str)
            {
                if(cpos == pos)
                {
                    while(*str && *str != delim)
                        str++;
                }
                else
                {
                    *wrk++ = *str;
                }
                if(*str == delim)
                    {cpos++;}
                if(*str) str++;
            }
            if(wrk > out)
                if(*(wrk - 1) == delim && cpos == pos)
                    wrk--;
            *wrk = 0;
        }
    }

    return out;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *str = ";;car;;dog;pet;elephant;;";
    char *output;

    for(int pos = 0; pos < 12; pos++)
    {
        output = dupAndDelete(str, ';', pos);
        if(output) printf("pos = %2d str = \"%s\"\n", pos, output);
        fflush(stdout);
        free(output);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie very, very good spot +++

Comment: @chqrlie to avoid not needed allocation but if reviewers like it another way :)

Comment: Actually I do not know why this code is here. I changed it many hours ago

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to construct a new csv line with the field number `pos` (1-based) removed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *removeField(const char *str, char delim, int pos)
{
    char *out;
    const char *p, *q;
    size_t len1, len2;
    int i, nsep = 0;

    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* skip the fields before the target field */
    for (p = str, i = 1; *p && i < pos; i++) {
        while (*p && *p != delim)
            p++;
        if (*p == delim) {
            p++;
            nsep++;
        }
    }
    /* skip the field to remove */
    for (q = p; *q && *q != delim; q++)
        continue;

    if (*q == delim) {
        /* if there are more fields, skip the delimiter */
        q++;
    } else {
        /* otherwise remove the trailing delimiter if the removed field was
           the last one but not the first one */
        if (pos > 1 && nsep == pos - 1)
            p--;
    }
    /* allocate the exact amount of bytes */
    len1 = p - str;
    len2 = strlen(q);
    out = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (out != NULL) {
        /* copy the left and right parts */
        memcpy(out, str, len1);
        memcpy(out + len1, q, len2 + 1);
    }
    /* return the new CSV line or NULL if allocation failure */
    return out;
}
```

Comment: now is correct. What I do not like is multiple returns and continue which IMO should be used as last resort only .UVted

Comment: @P__J: I agree in general, but I am OK with a separate return path for input validation failure as is the case here: `if (str == NULL) return NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution always works with valid input.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
        return 1;

    int x = atoi(argv[2]);

    char *s = argv[1], *d = argv[1];

    while (*s)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            --x;

            while (*s && *s != ';')
                ++s;

            if (*s)
                ++s;
            else
                break;
        }

        if (*s == ';')
            --x;

        *d++ = *s++;
    }

    if (*(d - 1) == ';')
        *(d - 1) = '\0';
    else
        *d = '\0';

    puts(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does not work https://godbolt.org/z/PrYraM

Comment: you miss the terminating null char https://godbolt.org/z/be1Ycz

Comment: practically it will not work with all border cases https://godbolt.org/z/8ofYW4.

Comment: It works perfectly fine. I just consider that ";" is an empty string.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland The OP did not specify how the program should behave in edge cases. I consider that ';' is the end of an entry except for the last entry. So when there is a ';' at the beginning of a string for example, it's treated as an empty string. I also don't handle the case where the string is empty.

Comment: `It works perfectly fine.` I do not think so 
https://godbolt.org/z/Yfxqsn `car` should be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can search a `;` with `strchr()`

This code searches the index you want to remove (1-based indexes)

```c
int main(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        // This is you argument
        int arg2 = i;

        printf("%ld: ", i);
        char *s = strdup(";car;dog;pet;elephant");

        char *curr = s;
        for (int i = 0; curr && i < arg2; i++)
            curr = strchr(curr + 1, ';');

        if (!curr)
        {
            printf("%s\n", s);
            free(s);
            continue;
        }

        char *next = strchr(curr + 1, ';');
        if (!next)
        {
            *curr = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            size_t offset = next - curr;
            size_t len = strlen(s);

            for (size_t i = curr - s; i < len; i++)
                s[i] = (i + offset < len ? s[i + offset + (curr == s)] : 0);
        }

        printf("%s\n", s);
        free(s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: same issues as another answer

Comment: no https://godbolt.org/z/P5ooMe

Answer (score -1):

Without any control/argument inspection, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Argument missing!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char * output = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(argv[1]));
    int cnt = 1;
    int memb = atoi(argv[2]);
    int outputp = 0;

    char* token = strtok(argv[1], ";");
    while (token != NULL) {
        if (cnt != memb) {
            strcat(output+outputp, token);
            outputp += strlen(token);
            strcat(output+outputp, ";");
            outputp++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, ";"); 
        cnt++;
    } 

    output[outputp-1] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", output);

    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

use:

```
$ ./a.out "car;dog;pet;elephant" 2
car;pet;elephant
$ ./a.out "car;dog;pet;elephant" 4
car;dog;pet
```

Edit: you can use `strsep()` instead of `strtok()`, then if your substring is empty, that will counts too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Argument missing!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char * output = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(argv[1])+1);
    int cnt = 1;
    int memb = atoi(argv[2]);
    int outputp = 0;
    char * token;

    while ((token = strsep(&argv[1], ";")) != NULL) {
        printf("'%s'\n", token);
        if (cnt != memb) {
            strcat(output+outputp, token);
            outputp += strlen(token);
            strcat(output+outputp, ";");
            outputp++;
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    output[outputp-1] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", output);

    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pedantic: add `1` more byte to `output` to execute `./a.out "foo;bar" 42` without overflow error

Comment: not working OK try ;car;dog;pet;elephant" 2

Comment: @pmg and P__J supports women in Poland - yes, I know - but as I start my comment: "Without any control/argument inspection"... There are so many thing what the programmer MUST to check before he/she releases the code, eg. check the input values.

Comment: @airween no it is a valid string. only the first element has length zero. It is a bad and heavy solution not taking border cases into the account.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland, yes, that's what I thought - check it as input: it mustn't start with ';'.

Comment: @airween what does it mean `musn't` ?

Comment: Why do you think that it must not. Empty string is the same good as not empty

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland "The solution is simply very bad." - it could be bad, but it depends on boundary conditions. The original question was "if the input is...". This solution solves that problem. I see your arguments, but as I wrote: it would be good to check so many things. Of course, I won't give a whole solution...

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland "Empty string is the same good as not empty" - but not in this case. Let the questioner makes the other cases...

Comment: @airween it is good in any cases. This code would never pass any code review in any company.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland - sure, I know. But it doesn't count here. It's just a solution for the problem above, nothing more.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland - changed, hope you'll like it :)

Comment: @airween another general remark - make it a function. This is generally the correct of doing it. Then test it using many cases. I do not like your solution as it uses very heavy functions for a very simple job. uncounable number of `strlen`s `strcat`s `strtok`s etc etc.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland: "make it a function" - of course, but let it make to original questioner. "I do not like your solution as it uses very heavy functions for a very simple job" - I dispute this opinion. IMHO it's always better to use a prepared function for the purpose. Don't want to reinvent the wheel.